# Bootstrap NavBar Responsive Weirdness

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page that uses Boostrap 3.2. When I re-size the window (chrome) to trigger the responsive design, the nav bar behaves very odd. It works once but any subsequent call doesn't work at all.

[image]

Oddly enough, i can't get to behave the same way in jsFiddle. So, I am going to present the dropbox link

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3740186/test/publications.html

The HTML for the nav bar

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="./Index.html">
          <img src="./images/logo_big.png" width="30" height="30" title="PIT" alt="PIT" />
          Test Pitt
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="./publications.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="./publications.html">Members</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="./publications.html">Research</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="./publications.html">Publications</a>
          </li>

          <li class="active">
            <a href="./publications.html">Teaching</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with your script at the end.

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  $("#" + e.target.id.replace("abs_", "btn_")).html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span> &nbsp; Hide Abstract");
});

$('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  $("#" + e.target.id.replace("abs_", "btn_")).html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down\"aria-hidden=\"true\"></span> &nbsp; Show Abstract");
});
```

You add those events to all `.collapse` elements, which include your menu when the window is re-sized.

Comment: What is different? Did you try the link that I have in the thread?

Comment: The structure is different. Remove the navbar-wrapper and container div and replace the nav element with the nav element I wrote my answer.

Comment: My bad, this wasn't it. Edited my answer.